# printing boolean in c++

Tags: c++, printing, boolean, cout

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std ;
int main()
{
    int a=5, b=4;
    cout<< a==b;
}
```

Why can't I print this code. How can I print boolean?

Comment: Have you tried to put `a==b` in brackets?

Answer (score 7):

Use [std::boolalpha](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/boolalpha/) to print as `true` or `false`. And add parenthesis, see Vaughn Cato answer for explanation.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std ;
int main()
{
    int a=5, b=4;
    cout<< boolalpha << (a==b);
}
```

Comment: I wrote that before you put the parenthesis around a==b.

Comment: Please explain why the parentheses are necessary for the asker.

Comment: @sftrabbit I didn't know but Vaughn Cato explained

Answer (score 7):

You are dealing with an operator precedence issue:

```
cout << a==b;
```

is interpreted as

```
(cout << a) == b;
```

because << has a higher precedence than ==.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put parenthesis around your test:

```
cout<< (a==b);
```

Comment: Because the operator<< has precedence over ==, like operator \* has precedence over + when you do 1 + 2 \* 3

Answer (score 0):

Put round brackets(parentheses) around `a==b`:

```
cout<< (a==b);
```

This is needed, because `<<` has greater operator precedence than `==`.

Comment: They are called also `round brackets`. Otherwise I agree parentheses is more accurate.

Comment: I checked that on wikipedia and I learnt that what I call brackets, i.e. {}, are "French brackets" (I live in France) :D

Comment: but why this works but mine doesn't? is it about operator precedence?

Comment: @user1559792 - Yes, it is because operator precedence.